# Need to use that counter variable outside since if i am calling that function am not getting output return

Tags: loops, promise, protractor

```
checkGridData(name: string, searchObj: ElementArrayFinder) {
    if (name != "") {
      let counter = 0;
      let beforesplit = name;
      let aftersplit = beforesplit.split("|");
      var countval = searchObj.count();
      return searchObj.count().then((count) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < aftersplit.length; i++) {
          let countval = searchObj.count();
          // expect(count).toBe(expectedRecords[i]);
          for (let j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            searchObj.get(j).getText().then(function (text) {
              if (text.indexOf(aftersplit[i]) !== -1) {
                expect(text).toContain(aftersplit[i]);
                ++counter
                //console.log("counter inside loop is" + counter)                 
              }
              return counter;

            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

I am new to protractore. I wrote a function below

I am calling this in another function.

```
var abc = this.CheckGridData(ProductData.AddEquipment.EquipmentSelection, ProductObj.ele_equipmentvalidation) 
    console.log("Counter value returned:" + abc)
```

And i am getting this error

> Counter value returned:ManagedPromise::5760 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}

I tried to do promise but I don't know how to do resolve promise. How to resolve inside for loop in the above, so that i can use it and know the concept? I tried various site but i couldn't understand how to resolve.

Comment: You should have edited the question you asked 3 hours ago instead of posting a new one.  They're the same.  You actually had someone ask for the complete function on the previous question, so I'm not sure why you wouldnt post it there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counter value not coming into another function in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969049/counter-value-not-coming-into-another-function-in-protractor)

Comment: There I Couldn't paste the full code n comment section . That's why. By mistake I pressed enter. I

Answer (score 0):

Because the function  `CheckGridData` return a promise, so the variable `abc` is a promise.

To consume the eventual value of promise, you have to use `then()` as below:

```
checkGridData(name: string, searchObj: ElementArrayFinder) {

  if (name != "") {
    let counter = 0;
    let beforesplit = name;
    let aftersplit = beforesplit.split("|");

    return searchObj.getText().then((texts) => {
      // texts is an string array of text of all elements of searchObj
      for (let i = 0; i < aftersplit.length; i++) { 
        if(texts.includes(aftersplit[i])) {
          ++counter;
        }
      }
      return counter;
    };
  }

}

var abc = this.CheckGridData(ProductData.AddEquipment.EquipmentSelection, 
                             ProductObj.ele_equipmentvalidation)

abc.then(function(count){
  console.log(count);
})
```

Comment: Thanks But if i am using in console log count is not coming. showing error. Still it's not returning value. Same error. To get value what should i do?

Comment: I update the code for function `checkGridData`, there are some issue in your code.

Comment: Here search object searchObj= element.all(by.css('.equipment-name')) . THis is list of element. So without loop how will iterate since your removed one loop?

Comment: **ManagedPromise {
  flow_:
   ControlFlow {
     propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
     activeQueue_:
      TaskQueue {
        name_: 'TaskQueue::5567',
        flow_: [Circular],
    This kind of error coming

Comment: I will explain clearly. What i am doing inside the function is splitting a value and store in aftersplit and i am iterating inside another for loop which is element.all count and inside that i am comparing using if. if it matches then counter value will be increased . if aftersplit value is 3. then count value will be 3 . once it come out of all for loop . i need to verify in if loop counter = aftersplit.length true. even if its not return in another function . just let me know how to verify counter outside for